# Add-In SSO: Error 5001 when trying to get logged in

Tags: node.js, azure, ms-office, office365, office-addins

I tried my luck with the tutorial regarding SSO in Office Add-Ins:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs

Unfortunately, it does not work for me. I assume the source for the error lies in the manifest XML. I run the Node.JS server on Azure with the following URL: https://a8templatedev.azurewebsites.net
I tried the solution with PowerPoint version 1711 (Build 8730.2127 Click-and-run) and PowerPoint Online (Build 16.0.8926.5631).

The add-in loads successfully, but when hitting the "Get my files"-button, it throws an internal error (5001). In addition, I cannot configure my URL a8templatedev.azurewebsites.net as the API in the app registration, as it always tells me the error, that I already own the domain and cannot add it. On the other side, I assume that I have to use this URL in the manifest, because localhost is not working and the resource/API-url should be the same in the manifest and the App registration portal.

Can anyone help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:ce44715c-8c4e-446b-879c-ea9ebe0f09c8-->
<OfficeApp 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
          xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
          xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>6b8fe481-75b4-461f-a223-9ba65934d444</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>0.0.0.1</Version>
  <ProviderName>Myjur Softwareentwicklung</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="SSO NodeJS Sample" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Shows how a node.js-based add-in can use single sign-on and the on-behalf-of flow to get Microsoft Graph data."/>
  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.contoso.com" />

  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <!--Begin TaskPane Mode integration. This section is used if there are no VersionOverrides or if the Office client version does not support add-in commands. -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Presentation" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://a8templatedev.azurewebsites.net/index.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <!-- End TaskPane Mode integration.  -->

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions> 

  <!-- Begin Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <!-- The Hosts node is required. -->
    <Hosts>
      <!-- Each host can have a different set of commands. -->
      <!-- Excel host is Workbook, Word host is Document, and PowerPoint host is Presentation. -->
      <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest. -->
      <Host xsi:type="Presentation">
        <!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!--"This code enables a customizable message to be displayed when the add-in is loaded successfully upon individual install."-->
          <GetStarted>
            <!-- Title of the Getting Started callout. The resid attribute points to a ShortString resource -->
            <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>

            <!-- Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
            <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>

            <!-- Points to a URL resource which details how the add-in should be used. -->
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <!-- Function file is a HTML page that includes the JavaScript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called. 
            Think of the FunctionFile as the code behind ExecuteFunction. -->
          <FunctionFile resid="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />

          <!-- PrimaryCommandSurface is the main Office Ribbon. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab. -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!-- Ensure you provide a unique id for the group. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your company name. -->
              <Group id="Contoso.Group1">
                <!-- Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                <Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label" />
                <!-- Icons. Required sizes 16,32,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX. -->
                <!-- Use PNG icons. All URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS. -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>

                <!-- Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu". -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                    <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                  </Icon>

                  <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <!-- Provide a URL resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <!-- You can use resources across hosts and form factors. -->
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://a8templatedev.azurewebsites.net/Images/Button16x16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://a8templatedev.azurewebsites.net/Images/Button32x32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://a8templatedev.azurewebsites.net/Images/Button80x80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://a8templatedev.azurewebsites.net/Functions/FunctionFile.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://a8templatedev.azurewebsites.net/index.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <!-- ShortStrings max characters==125. -->
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Add-in2" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Group1Label" DefaultValue="SSO NodeJS2" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <!-- LongStrings max characters==250. -->
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to show the sample." />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Sample' button to get started." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>

    <WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>{APPID}</Id>
      <Resource>api://a8templatedev.azurewebsites.net/{APPID}</Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
          <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
        <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
      </Scopes>
    </WebApplicationInfo>
  </VersionOverrides>
  <!-- End Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->

</OfficeApp>
```

{APPID} is only used as a placeholder here.

[image: PowerPoint error]

[image: App registration]

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. The "api://... " domain that you use in the app registration must be an exact match for the domain used in the Resource value in the manifest. Your screenshot indicates that it is different. When you are developing, it should be localhost:3000 in both places.
2. You cannot register an app with an azure.websites.com domain. You must use a domain that you own. The error message is telling you that someone else owns it.